# Is there a way to take a dataset that contains floats between 1-7 and set a range to it so that I only use numbers between 2.6 and 5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.loadtxt('Area_-116_32.txt', usecols = 2)
plt.hist(data, bins=40, range=[2.6,5], log=10)
e= np.array(data) 
condition = np.mod(e)>2.6 and np.mod(e)<5
```

this gives an error of

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [34], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 condition = np.mod(e)>2.6 and np.mod(e)<5

TypeError: remainder() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 1 were given
```

[example of some of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80SU8.png)

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you want to achieve but `numpy`s `mod` method  (the modulo operator `%`) expects *two* arguments. Check the documentation of [numpy.mod](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mod.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [numpy's clip function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)

`numpy.clip(a, a_min, a_max, out=None, **kwargs`

**Edit** if you want to remove those values from the array instead of clipping them, you just need to re-make your array:

```
>>> x=np.array([3, 6, 7, -2, -5, -1, -1, 3, 1, -1, -2, -1, -5, -1])
>>> x[(x>-2) & (x<6)]
array([ 3, -1, -1,  3,  1, -1, -1, -1])
```

Comment: numpy.clip(a, a_min, a_max, out=None, **kwargs 
I tried this and the length of the data has remained the same so nothing's been cut off @zaero Divide

Comment: aha, you want to "strip" those values out, not "clip" them